# How to substitute an expression in side a particular head or inside a particular pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching

Let say I have any expression

```
ex= f[h[r[x y]]] g[x z]
```

and I want to replace the `x` with `w`, but only for the `x` within the head `f`. Is there any simple way to do that?

Another, if I want to substitute an expression, say `x`, but only if it it is inside a pattern, say `complicateExpression x`, how can I do it? Of course, I can use the rule

```
complicateExpression x -> complicateExpression w
```

But this often means copy and paste `complicateExpression`

Comment: For the replacement of x inside f you could perhaps use a rule like ```{f[args__]:>f@@({args}/.{x->w})}```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ex /. a_f :> (a /. x -> w)
```

> ```
>  f[h[r[w y]]] g[x z]
> ```

```
ex2 = f[h[r[complicatedexpression  x ]]] g[x z];

ex2 /. ( p : complicatedexpression) x :> p w
```

> ```
> f[h[r[complicatedexpression w]]] g[x z]
> ```

Comment: What if f is Inactive[f]? How to make that work?

Comment: @ablmf,  something like   `ex4 = Inactivate[f[h[r[x y]]] g[x z], f]; ex4 /. a : (Inactive[f]@__) :> (a /. x -> w)` or `ex3 = Inactive[f][h[r[x y]]] g[x z];
ex3 /. a : (Inactive[f]@__) :> (a /. x -> w)`?